# DataGridView DataBinding get selected object from Combobox

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, one of column is `Combobox (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)` binded to property of objects. Then DataGridView format cell it calls `ToString()` of my objects. So i combo list just a strings and then I try to select from `combobox` I get an error because the program trying to set string to my object. How to solve it? Just then select from `combobox` get an object value not string.

I have an collection of objects (`MyObject`) that contains a property

```
public Reason Kind { get; set; }
```

Reason has a method ToString() that DataGridView calls automaticly. So while I select value from combobox it not `Reason` object, its just a `string`

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DisplayMemberPath property on the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

```
<DataGridViewComboBoxColumn DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName" />
```

Comment: I think u talk about WPF but Im using WinForms

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set which property you want to show and which you want to get as value. If you don't set the value member, then you'll get back your object.

So, given

```
public class Reason
{
    public Reason()
    {}
    public Reason(string name, int value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Hi, I am {0} and I contain [Name:{1}, Value:{2}]", GetType(), Name, Value);
    }
}
```

And assuming you just have `Form1` with `DataGridView`, containing just one combo column, then.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Kind = new Collection<Reason>();
        Kind.Add(new Reason("First", 0));
        Kind.Add(new Reason("Second", 1));

        Column1.DataSource = Kind;
        Column1.DisplayMember = "Name";

        // Do not set value member to get the actual selected object
        // If you explicitly set it, you'll get you property value
        // Column1.ValueMember = "value" 

        dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var cmb = args.Control as ComboBox;
                if (cmb == null)
                    return;

                cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, eventArgs) =>
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(cmb.SelectedItem.ToString());
            };
    }

    public Collection<Reason> Kind { get; set; }
}
```

Then selected item would be typeof Reason and print out e.g.
`Hi, I am WindowsFormsApplication1.Reason and I contain [Name:Second, Value:1]`